# How to add items to multiple projects

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I'm trying to develop an vsix extension that will deploy different items to differente projects, example: Project A will get item A, Project B, item B, is this possible with a vsix extension, I'm searching the internet but can't find any information or example of this.

Comment: Could you share us much more detailed information about how you "deploy" items in your side or just add new items to projects?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, right now everytime that need to create a "new component" on my project I have to create a class in one project and then create another file in a different project all inside the same visual studio solution. Then at run time there is an engine that find those to files and match some properties between then.

Comment: I would like create a visual studio extension that would create those files in each of the projects instead of copy/paste and rename process that I use now

Comment: Firstly, if you add them to your project manually, does it work? I mean that whether your project could call them in the same project(Not different project in the same solution), if it works well. Maybe you could just create your custom project template by yourself. Or just add custom item template, and then add them to your project manually every time. I didn't find a workaround which could deploy different items to different projects automatically.

Comment: I could call then on the same project, the problem is that this is a product that exists for some time this way and I can't refactor it, that would have major implications on other parts of the product. At the moment I have a custom item template with the two different files and I can add then on the same project, if I could just copy one to the other project that would be perfect. But like you sad I also can't find a work around for it....So I suppose that the solution is create all the item in one project and then manually copy one the files to the other project.

Comment: I think so, at least, I didn't find other better workaround except this one:)